# Looking for proper algorithm for the given problem

Tags: python, algorithm

I got a Python task from my teacher, but I can't figure out how to approach such a task and what algorithm should I use.

Let's say I have two boxes and two blocks. Each block has a weight per box, for example:

```
{
   "boxes":{
      "Box 1":{
         "Block 1":2,
         "Block 2":5
      },
      "Box 2":{
         "Block 1":4,
         "Block 2":3
      }
   }
}
```

For each block I have to choose the right box with the lowest possible weight.
So in the above case, the output should look like this:

```
{
   "Box 1":{
      "Block 1":2
   },
   "Box 2":{
      "Block 2":3
   }
}
```

This example looks trivial, but later in the task, the following limitations may apply:

1. All boxes can have a set limit (the same for all boxes) on how many blocks it can hold;
2. There may be situations where a given block may be placed in only some of the boxes. So the block must be placed in one of the allowed boxes, for example:

```
{
   "boxes":{
      "Box 1":{
         "Block 1":2,
         "Block 2":5,
         "Block 3":20
      },
      "Box 2":{
         "Block 1":4,
         "Block 2":3
      }
   }
}
```

So in this case, block 3 can only be assigned to Box 1.

My first thought was that I should start with blocks that have weights for 1 box, then for 2, etc., but I do not know if this solution will be optimal if I want to implement the same block limit for all boxes (e.g. that it can allocates box of up to 5 blocks) Maybe I should use decision trees and look for the smallest sum of weights for all boxes?

Comment: Sounds like a variation of the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: When you write "block", do you mean "brick"?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for confusion, I have updated jsons to be also as "block".

Comment: What are the constraints for the problem? Maximum number of boxes? Maximum number of unique blocks? Maximum number of blocks per box?

Comment: @user3386109 The number of blocks and boxes can be any number, the only limitation is the number of blocks per box. 

For example:
If there are 10 blocks that have only one weight for Box 1 among all boxes, and Box 1 can only hold 5 blocks, then only the 5 blocks with the lowest weight should be assigned to that box.

Comment: @dejwux It makes a big difference to the algorithm design whether the maximum numbers are 10 blocks in 5 boxes versus 10 billion blocks in 50 million boxes.